# SQL grouping different column values of same meaning

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am tasked to match two columns together using SQL query in postgres. In my task i need to match two columns of different name but same meaning together using the same ID. Below i would illustrate this :

table 1

```
name                 ,Group
Terminal point 1     ,Terminal 
Terminal point town 1,Terminal 
Terminal point 2     ,Terminal
Terminal point 3     ,Terminal
```

table 2

```
Name      ,ID
Terminal 1,T01 
Terminal 1,T01 
Terminal 2,T002
Terminal 3,T0003
```

Output table

```
Name                  ,Group    , ID 
Terminal Point 1      , Terminal, T01
Terminal Point town 1 , Terminal, T01
Terminal Point 2      , Terminal, T002
Terminal Point 3      , Terminal, T0003
```

i have tried using group by and inner joins and also substr of the first and last character of the ID but i am unable to do that as len is not allowed in postgres sql query. Any suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the match could be something this:

```
select t1.*, t2.id
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.name = replace(name, 'point ', '');
```

At the very least, some sort of string manipulation seems to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) like

```
select
  to_tsvector('Terminal point 1') @@ plainto_tsquery('Terminal 1'), -- True
  to_tsvector('terminal Point town 1') @@ plainto_tsquery('Terminal 1'), -- True
  to_tsvector('Terminal point 2') @@ plainto_tsquery('Terminal 1'), -- False
  to_tsvector('Terminal point 2') @@ plainto_tsquery('Terminal 2'); -- True
```

So your query should be

```
select
  *
from
  table1 t1
    join (select distinct * from table2) t2 on (to_tsvector(t1.name) @@ plainto_tsquery(t2.name))
```